# What happens when Capturing USB Packets using Wireshark

Tags: usb, wireshark

I am trying to capture the packets sent by a Mouse to a host PC using Wireshark.

Operating System - Ubuntu 12.04
Wireshark - 1.8.2

Problem 1.) Before I plug in the USB Mouse, when I start the capture on the USB Bus, I see some communication between the USB Host Controller(Root Hub) and the Host. Why does this happen when the Mouse is not yet connected?

Problem 2.) The basic order of communication between the host and USB device according to the USB specification is
a.) Token Packet.
b.) Data Packet.
c.) Handshake Packet.
What we see in Wireshark is a URB Submit and URB Complete packets. 
Do these packets represent only the data packets? 
Do we not see the Token and Handshake Packets in Wirehsark?
What does Wireshark exactly try to capture?